# Smooth performance with live graph updated every 1/30 th of second

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I wanted a suggestion from you guys regarding drawing and scrolling performance. The requirement is - I have to draw a graph with sound volume's values updated at 30 fps. And I need to draw this graph and simultaneously scroll to fit in the new values. So the length(width) of the graph is unlimited. So please suggest the best way of accomplishing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitmapData has a `scroll()` method that you can use - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#scroll()

Basically every frame, you only draw one column of pixel's worth of data (your BitmapData will be the view of your sound, and each column of pixels one capture's worth of data) - for the most part, you're probably only going to be using `setPixel()` to set the volume value.

Keep moving along, one column of pixels for one frame of data, then when you get to your threshold (the very right-hand side of the BitmapData), use `scroll()` to move the data one pixel left (you'll lose the left-most column of pixels), then continue drawing in the last column (right) of pixels. You'll create a constantly updating volume display.

Finally use `lock()` and `unlock()` before and after drawing to stop Flash from updating the screen in the meantime.

I'd advise having some sort of limit however - items that grow infinitely = big problems later

**Edit**

Here's some code. This is taking me 0ms (using `getTimer()` on the debug player) to render. You will eventually run into problems, as the volume Vector is growing unbounded, which is never a good thing. If you only need to hold the last x number of frames, then this code is even easier.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var m_bmd:BitmapData    = null;
        private var m_vol:Vector.<int>  = null;
        private var m_currVol:int       = 0;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            // create our bmd
            this.m_bmd = new BitmapData( 400.0, 200.0, false, 0 );

            // add it to the stage
            var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap( this.m_bmd );
            this.addChild( b );

            // create our volume array
            this.m_vol = new Vector.<int>();

            // set our current volume
            this.m_currVol = this.m_bmd.height / 2;

            // start our volume listener
            this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._onEnterFrame );
        }

        private function _onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void
        {
            var start:int = getTimer();

            // update our volume and add it to our array
            this.m_currVol += int( ( Math.random() * 10.0 ) - 5.0 ); // adds a random int between -5 and 5
            this.m_currVol  = ( this.m_currVol < 0 ) ? 0 : ( this.m_currVol > this.m_bmd.height ) ? this.m_bmd.height : this.m_currVol; // clamp it to the bitmap data height
            this.m_vol[this.m_vol.length] = this.m_currVol;

            // lock our bitmap
            this.m_bmd.lock();

            // clear the bitmap
            this.m_bmd.fillRect( this.m_bmd.rect, 0 );

            // go through and draw our volumes (for max the size of the bmd)
            var len:int     = ( this.m_vol.length < this.m_bmd.width ) ? this.m_vol.length : this.m_bmd.width;
            var startX:int  = ( this.m_vol.length < this.m_bmd.width ) ? 0 : this.m_vol.length - this.m_bmd.width;
            for ( var i:int = 0; i < len; i++ )
                this.m_bmd.setPixel( i, this.m_vol[startX + i], 0xffff00 );

            // unlock our bitmap
            this.m_bmd.unlock();

            trace( "This took " + ( getTimer() - start ) + "ms to render" );
        }       

    }

}
```

Add in a scrollbar to change the `startX` variable (by default, it will always show the last amount of data), and you're there

Comment: Hi Divilly,
thanks for taking time to explain, but what exactly I need is a scrollable data, i.e. I don't want to loose the data at the left side, rather I want to mask it out, and a scroller will be visible once it crosses the specified width, so at any point of time, one can scroll to the left and see the whole graph. This is what the challenge is... to me at least.

Comment: in that case, simply keep a vector of numbers for the volume. draw from the end of the vector to (end - numItems) for the data vis, and use the scrollbar (not connected to anything - you just want the value out of it) to determine that start point if needed.

Comment: then you must be doing something wrong. I've updated my answer with some code. It takes me next to no time to draw this. Run the code to see what it's doing. All that's left to do is to add your scrollbar

Comment: hey Divilly, thanks so much for your efforts, your code made me think in different way. One thing I don't prefer bitmap data is pixel effect, the lines won't be as smooth as sprite.graphics.lineTo... but have to compromise for onething if we want to achieve another :) your help is appreciated...

Comment: you could also try this: http://www.simppa.fi/blog/extremely-fast-line-algorithm-as3-optimized/ - I'm not sure how the results would look, but you can give it a go. If it makes the graph look better, you could also increase the x spacing between each point (from 1 pixel to, say 4)